# I got an error about gets function and buffer heaps in C code

Tags: c, data-structures, buffer, gets

```
void main() {

char command;
element e;
TreeNode *root = NULL;
TreeNode *tmp;

do {
    help();
    command = getchar();
    fflush(stdin);
    switch (command) {
    case 'i':
        printf("Word:");
        gets(e.word);
        printf("Meaning:");
        gets(e.meaning);
        insert_node(&root, e);
        break;
    case 'd':
        printf("Word:");
        gets(e.word);
        delete_node(&root, e);
        break;
    case'p':
        display(root);
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case's':
        printf("Word:");
        gets(e.word);
        tmp = search(root, e);
        if (tmp != NULL)
            printf("Meaning:%s\n", e.meaning);
        break;

    }
} while (command != 'q');
}
```

This is the main code not whole one.

I studied data-struct and tried made a dictionary by binary tree search but if I run this code the first gets get an error but other `gets()` are not crashed and also the first one's color is different.

[image]

the error code is warning C4013

I know that the error code is not define specific function but I already wrote the header files, `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`.

The other error is input buffer when I running this code, the word and meaning are mixed.

[image]

i heard this error happen by input buffer and I know it

so I coded // fflush(stdin) after // command = getchar();

but the error doesn't solved

I want to why this happening and solve the problem thanks

Comment: whait is the error exactly? please translate in english.

Comment: the error message is 'warning c4013 'gets' undefined assuming extern returning int'

Comment: what did you mean *I wrote the header files*? you need to add this statement at the very beginning of your program `#include <stdio.h>`. I do not see it in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Error code C4013 of MS Visual Studio means `'function' undefined; assuming extern returning int`.

It is a warning so when you run the program it appears that the function that was undefined needs something else then what you pass it, or returs something else than an int, and then it crashes.

So you must first fix this warning: find out which function the compiler complains about and then properly define it and call it.

Comment: the error function is gets() but I coded header files <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h>